# Restoring Chrome cookies

Tags: macos, google-chrome, cookies

I use Google Chrome as my browser. I deleted Chrome cookies and there are some files that were stored in the cookies for a note taking web application I use. I want to restore the files that were stored in the cookies I deleted. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you have a Time Machine backup?

Comment: I think so but i am not sure how to use it

Comment: In the setting, time machine is set to "Back Up automatically"

Answer (score 1):

Use the **Enter Time Machine** command from the Time Machine menu to restore the folder `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome` from a Time Machine backup made before you deleted the cookies. Note: all changes to your Chrome settings and preferences will be reset to the time of the backup.

Make sure Chrome is not running.

Here's [Apple's guide to restoring files with Time Machine](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/restore-files-mh11422/mac).